# Multiple pronunciations of "where"

Tags: british-english, australian-english, where

I've been an *Australian* English speaker my whole life but this was pointed out to me recently. Apparently I've been pronouncing "where" differently or incorrectly? Most of the people around me pronounce it this way:
/wɛː/ (or like this: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/where)
However I found myself pronouncing it this way:
/wɪəː/ (like saying "hear" but replacing the first letter with the usual /w/ sound)

Example of both: https://vocaroo.com/i/s0DYaRzH5heN

Is this an Australian English thing? I only know of one other person who says it like I do. Or am I just pronouncing it wrong?

Comment: I'd say that if you are being understood, then you are not mispronouncing the word. There is a wide variation in how "where" is pronounced in the English speaking world.

Comment: `my whole life` How old are you (30s)? And in which part of Australia do you live?

Comment: Generally, (most) dictionaries provide pronunciation for AmE and BrE. Maybe some may even provide for AusE, which I suspect would be similar to if not the same as BrE.

Comment: I'm an Australian, lived here nearly 60 years, travelled all over the country, and I can assure you that the way you pronounce it is **not** a recognised Australian accent. It sounds to me more like a *New Zealand* accent.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Ah right, 20 years old. Lived in Sydney my whole life.

Comment: @Chappo I have absolutely no idea how I learnt this pronunciation then.. No-one in my family says it this way either.

Comment: Do you happen to come from an East Asian background?

Comment: @Chappo That's an interesting observation about it sounding Kiwi. I've never studied the antipodean phonological diphthongs, but this seems like a case of *differentiation*, where you move one sound further away from its neighbor; here raising it. I wonder how he'd do with a Glaswegian /hwer/. ,->

Comment: @tchrist my Kiwi colleague pronounces *hair* as *hear*, which is what prompted my comment. The vowel shift (excuse my ignorance of the correct term) is more obvious in words like *hat* (pronounced more like *het*) and *six* (more like *sux*). A strong Maori influence can sometimes be discerned too, with "wh" being pronounced as a faint "f" at the start of some words. "Whaka yeah" must be used cautiously...

Answer (score 1):

As a native English speaker from the South East of England, I can interpret your audio recording in two ways, depending on whether I have tuned into an Australian accent or not. When I'm unaware of your accent, I hear "we're" (we are). When I tune into an Australian accent, I hear "where", as you intended.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I pronounce "hear" differently XD

You seem to pronounce it as an /hiːr/, I would pronounce it /hɪə/.

Although unusual, since /ɛː/ in RP should stay /ɛː/ in AuE as far as I gather, I still find it quite comprehensible.

I would say yes, you may be pronouncing it "wrong", but it should still be widely understood, so don't be bothered by it.